# how do you install jquery in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Is it just a matter of installing the jquery.jq file in the javascript folder and linking to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, delete the default js files and place your own and then include it in your layouts.

Answer (score 6):

What version of Rails are you running?

For Rails 2.x, you will probably also want to install the `jrails` plugin to provide jquery versions of all the javascript helpers like `link_to_remote` and `periodically_call_remote`.

For Rails 3.0, you should download the `jquery-ujs` version of `rails.js` from [github](http://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) to achieve the same functionality.

Otherwise, you'll have to write all your AJAX manually if you just remove `prototype` and `scriptaculous` and drop in `jquery.js`.